# Trigger ItemSend when item is being sent from outbox using addon

Tags: c#, email, outlook, ms-office

I'm writing an outlook addon that triggers when the Send button is sent on an email, if certain conditions are met a pop up comes up asking if the user is sure they want to send the email.

This works perfectly. However, A lot of emails that get sent are passed into outlook through another program and go into the drafts folder and are slowly sent out. Is there an Event handler for when an email is sent that doesn't rely on the send button being clicked?

EDIT:

I've found that the Send() method can be called to send an email - would it be possible to check if this method is called and when it is to run my code?

Comment: they dont go to drafts to be sent,they go to the outbox. drafts maybe be an in the middle process when you take long enough to form the message before being sent it maybe auto saved there or saved there if you ask

Comment: For some reason the program we send them through seems to put them in drafts. I know that doesn't make sense and that the Outbox is where outgoing emails are stored.

Comment: A message can be sent from any folder, Outbox is just an eye candy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the external app is using the Outlook Object Model to send the messages, `Application.ItemSend` event will still fire. Otherwise the best you can of is use `Items.ItemAdd` event on the Sent Items folder - it will trigger after a message is actually sent and moved to the Sent Items folder.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, I have tried both of these, for some reason the items never trigger the ItemAdd method if it is set to the Outbox. They trigger it if I set it to the drafts folder though. I can get a pop up to appear and hold the message but as soon as the pop up closes, the email sends no matter what. Could this mean the external application isn't using the outlook object model?

Comment: I've just noticed your answer mentions the SentItems folder - I need my AddOn to catch messages before they're sent in order for them to be blocked on certain conditions

Comment: Items.ItemAdd event fires only after the message is sent, so you cannot block it. Application.ItemSend event fires only if the message is sent using the Outlook Object Model or the UI. It does not fire if a message is sent using Simpel or Extended MAPI.